# Script Shrew VPN

Tags: shell-scripting, shrew

I have the Shrew client installed in order to connect to a cisco VPN.

(side note: anyconnect royally blows and I spent several hours trying to get it to work; I had shrew running within 2 minutes of installing it.)

Anyway, I can connect just fine and it works.

What I need to do is schedule the connection.  For example, once a day I want a process to start shrew, auto connect to the vpn then run a SQL script.  Once the script is finished I want shrew to disconnect from the VPN.

So far I have the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\ShrewSoft\VPN Client\ipsecc.exe" -r ClientSite -u MyUser -p MyPassword -a
```

When this runs, Shrew connects and starts the VPN interface.  However, that line doesn't return until someone clicks the "disconnect" button.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disconnecting**

ShrewSoft VPN doesn't have any command line parameters to disconnect.
The only simple alternative is to send a taskkill to the process to close, e.g;

```
taskkill.exe /IM ipsecc.exe
```

Of course, this will affect all ipsecc processes should you have multiple VPNs active.

**Non Blocking Start**

You may want to use something like the "start" command to run the ipsecc command without blocking the batch process.

```
C:\Windows\system32>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've open sourced some code which manages shrew connections and re-connections. UI is well isolated from the core so it would be easily modifiable to do whatever you need.

Check it out at https://github.com/CamW/shrew-reconnect if you're interested.